# Word for something that cannot be calculated "back"?

Tags: relations

Sorry if this is a duplicate / not something allowed in here, I do not use the math section often.

I am looking for a word to describe something that cannot be calculated "backwards", once it is calculated "forwards". Maybe it is a relation of some sort?

One example might be found in cryptography I think, where, for example, when you calculate a compressed hash out of something, you cannot really calculate the original information back from the hash. What is that phenomenon called? Are there different words to describe something like that?

Comment: Possibly ["one-way function"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_function)?

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth I think one-way functions could be some of the instances of this? Is there a more general definition / term to describe this "one-wayism"? I mean if I have a rock and I grind it to sand, that relationship between the sand and the original rock would also be pretty one-way, as it would be quite impossible to construct the original rock back from the sand. Would you describe this example simply as an "example of one-way relationship" or something else?

Comment: The first thing that came to mind was the notion of a function which is not injective. If a function is injective, then unequal inputs lead to unequal outputs, i.e. $x\neq y \implies f(x)\neq f(y)$. This is also equivalently stated as $f(x)=f(y) \implies x=y$. If a function is not injective, you cannot necessarily have $f^{-1}(f(x)) = x$ or $f(f^{-1}(x))=x$, i.e. you cannot retrieve the input despite knowing the output and the function. An example is $f(x) = x^2$. If I tell you $f(x) = 4$, you can't tell me for sure whether $x$ was $2$ or $-2$.

Comment: Isn't it unrealistic to expect one definition that includes the "one-way functions" and the rock and sand example? The first example already carries a nice definition and the second can probably be described by a physicist in terms of entropy. I don't see a need for one formal definition to include all these phenomena in one go.

Comment: Perhaps you looking for "non-reversible", which describes an operation which cannot be done in the opposite direction in a one-to-one fashion. The opposite will, of course, be that the operation is "reversible".

Comment: @EeveeTrainer Aha! That's a good one and pretty familiar to me, especially in the context of functions. So I guess I could call things that have one-way relationships as things which relationship is not injective? Then again, why wouldn't I just call not injective relationships as one-way relationships...

Comment: @JohnOmielan Yes! That is definitely the word I was looking for! It was completely lost on me, I am not a native english speaker either so no wonder. :) I would mark that one as an accepted answer, if you post it.

Comment: I've done as you requested, and am glad I could be of help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you're looking for "non-reversible", which describes an operation which cannot be done in the reverse direction in a one-to-one fashion. The opposite will, of course, be that the operation is "reversible".